# Is there any limit on the number of e-mails in a given folder with Courier IMAP?

Tags: imap, courier

I'm not running into a problem or anything, I was just curious about this when I saw I have 2 folders with around 20,000 items in each.  Everything works fine (using Thunderbird), but I couldn't find anything with Google about this.  Anyone ever heard of a limit on this with Courier IMAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the file system:

- FAT16: 512 per folder
- FAT32: 65534 per folder
- NTFS: 4,294,967,295

In Linux, the limits are based on the number of inodes and the size of the drive. Note that ext2/ext3 and others that use the standard inode directory layout have a limit of ~32,000 sub directories in a directory.

For 20,000 files, use a file system that stores files in a tree structure, rather than the list structure as used by ext2/ext3, UFS, FAT16/FAT32. You might also want to increase the size of the directory cache.

Comment: The dir_index feature makes ext2/ext3/ext4 use hashed  b-trees  to  speed  up lookups in large directories. Can be set with tune2fs(8) in the unlikely case it isn't already (probably a really old fs).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no limit of mails per IMAP folder in Courier IMAP or the IMAP4rev1 specification.

But the underlying file system on which the Maildir files are hosted could have a hard limit for the number of files per directory or at least may suffer performance degradation if a certain number of files in a single directory is exceeded.

20,000 mails/files should not be a problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just for other people's information here. I run an e-mail host and I've seen inboxes and mail folders with over a million messages in them.  Granted, they are really slow and it causes other issues at that point with just loading the folder, but it will work eventually.  I usually call people out after their inbox grows past 40,000 messages or so.